# Richtige Verwendung von Adjektivendungen

Tags: adjective-ending

Der Satz lautet:

> Ich versuche nämlich, **alle meine Mahlzeiten** innerhalb von vier oder fünf Stunden zu konsumieren.

Ich würde gerne wissen, warum sagt man nicht “alle meine**n** Mahlzeiten“.
Sollte man nicht im Falle eines Akkusativs, dem zweiten Adjektiv eine Endung **-en** hinzuzufügen, wenn das Substantiv plural ist?

z.B. ”Ich kenne die gut**en** Leute”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mein ist kein Adjektiv sondern ein Possessivpronomen. Die Konjugation kann hier nachgeschlagen werden: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein#Inflection

Da *Mahlzeiten* im Akkusativ Plural steht, wird die Form **meine** benötigt.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wo überall Possessivartikel noch als Possessivpronomen bezeichnet werden. Das scheint immer noch üblich zu sein. Die Sprachwissenschaft hat längst zwischen "pronominalem und begleitendem" Gebrauch z.B. der Possessiva unterschieden bzw. spricht gleich von _Possessivartikeln_ in Abgrenzung zu _Possessivpronomen_. Die Deklination der Possessivpronomen, die es auch gibt, deckt sich nicht vollständig mit der der Possessivartikel. Im von dir genannten Verweis heißen die Artikel 'determiner', zur pronominalen Funktion gibt es eine Anmerkung unterhalb der Tabelle. Wichtiger als die ...

Comment: ... Deklination der Artikel ist die Steuerung nachfolgender Adjektive, die sind hier jedoch nicht problematisiert. Eigentlich geht es hier um den syntaktischen Status von _alle_, dazu schreibe ich kurz eine Antwort.

Comment: Ich hab's damals in der Grundschule so gelernt

Comment: Ja, in der Schule wird das wohl oft so unterrichtet. Wie es heute in Deutschland unterrichtet wird, weiß ich nicht, vermute aber, dass man einen Unterschied zwischen Begleitern und Adjektiven und Pronomen macht.

Answer (score 3):

Nomen treten in Sätzen alleinstehend auf

> **Katzen** sind **Einzelgänger**

oder mit Artikeln

> **die Katze** ist krank / **unsere Katze** ist krank

oder mit Adjektiven

> alle lieben **kleine Katzen**

oder mit Artikeln + Adjektiven

> **die kleinen Katzen** auf YouTube kennen wahrscheinlich alle.

Diese vier Möglichkeiten gibt es für den Standardaufbau einer Nominalgruppe. Wenn Artikel dabei sind, stehen diese in der Nominalgruppe vorne. Die Artikel steuern die Deklinationsweise der nachfolgenden Adjektive:

> de**r** klein**e** Hund - ein kleine**r** Hund.

Die Regel dafür ist:

**Wenn ein Artikel die Genus-, Kasus- und Numerusmarkierungen trägt**, bekommt das nachfolgende Adjektiv

- im Nominativ Singular die Endung **-e**,
- im Akkusativ Singular Femininum und Neutrum die Endung **-e**
- sonst immer **-en**, also im Plural, Dativ und Genitiv immer, und
  **auch im Akkusativ Maskulinum Singular**.

Diese Art der Adjektivdeklination heißt **schwache Adjektivdeklination**.

Adjektive können jedoch auch allein die Genus-, Kasus- und Numerusmarkierungen tragen und werden dann dekliniert wie die bestimmten Artikel. Diese Art der Deklination heißt **starke Adjektivdeklination**. Sie gilt, wenn es keinen Artikel gibt:

> Das ist doch kalt**er** Kaffee (= uninteressant)

oder wenn das Artikelwort unveränderlich ist oder keine Endung tragen kann, wie es bei den Possessivartikeln teilweise der Fall ist. Ganz unveränderliche Artikelwörter finden sich unter Indefinita (meist als "indefinite Pronomen" bezeichnet), dazu gehört z.B. auch ***etwas*** in der Funktion als Artikelwort:

> Ich trinke meinen Tee immer mit etwas frisch**er** Milch.

Die Regel funktioniert hier so: *Mit* verlangt den Dativ, *etwas* ist unveränderlich, also muss das Adjektiv *frisch* die Genus- (*feminin*), Kasus- (*Dativ*) und Numerusendung (*Singular*) tragen, und die ist **-er**.

Das Problem in der gestellten Frage ist nun, dass es hier kein Adjektiv gibt:

> **alle** ist Indefinitum (klassische Bezeichnung "indefinites Pronomen"), hier in Artikelfunktion,

und

> **meine** ist ein weiterer Artikel, nämlich ein Possessivartikel.

Artikelkombinationen kommen vor, sind jedoch selten. Man findet öfter die **nicht veränderbaren** Indefinita **all**, **solch**, **manch** und den Frageartikel **welch** als eine Art Vorschaltartikel, hinter denen nachfolgende Artikelwörter und Adjektive nach den üblichen Regeln dekliniert werden:

> All dies**e** neu**en** Informationen sind heute ein bisschen viel für mich.

Darum handelt es sich hier jedoch nicht, da **alle** in seiner Artikelfunktion eine Numerus- (*Plural*) und Kasusendung (*Nominativ oder Akkusativ*) trägt, nämlich das **-e**                          .

Wie nachfolgende Artikel und Adjektive dann zu deklinieren sind, muss leider im Einzelfall nachgeschlagen werden, da sich die Indefinita in diesem Punkt uneinheitlich verhalten. Für *alle* gilt:

Ein nachfolgendes **Adjektiv** hinter ***alle*** wird schwach dekliniert. Es muss also heißen

> alle frisch zubereitet**en** Mahlzeiten.

Im angefragten Beispiel ist ***meine*** jedoch ein **Artikel** und wird wie ein Artikel dekliniert:

> mein**e** / dies**e** / di**e** ... frisch zubereitet*en* Mahlzeiten

Und auch in Kombination mit vorangestelltem **alle** bleibt diese Artikel-Deklination erhalten, so dass **alle** und ein nachfolgendes weiteres Artikelwort im Plural parallel dekliniert werden:

> all**e** mein**e** / all**e** dies**e** / all**e** jen**e** ... frisch zubereitet*en* Mahlzeiten

Im Plural hat man **bei der Kombination mit anderen Artikeln** oft die Wahl zwischen deklinierbarem **alle**:

- N: *Alle meine Freunde* sitzen jetzt zu Hause und gucken Fußball;
- A: Ich habe *alle meine Freunde* eingeladen;
- D: Er ist *mit allen seinen Freunden* gekommen;
- G: Zur Freude *aller seiner alten Freunde* ist er in seine Heimatstadt zurückgekehrt;

und nicht deklinierbarem **all**:

- N: *All seine Freunde* sind jetzt im Ausland.
- A: Er hat *all seine Freunde* angerufen.
- D: Er hat *mit all seinen Freunden* Streit gekriegt.
- G: Er kennt die Telefonnummern *all seiner Freunde* auswendig.

Im Singular gibt es überwiegend nur das unveränderliche **all** vor einem Possessivartikel:

> *alles mein Geld

geht nicht, es muss heißen:

- N: *All sein Geld* ist weg. Analog:
- A: Er musste *all seinen Mut* zusammennehmen.
- D: *Mit all seiner Intelligenz und all seinem Fleiß* hat er die Führerscheinprüfung dennoch nicht geschafft.
- G: *Trotz all seines Wissens* halten ihn viele Leute für ungebildet.

Wenn hier der Possessivartikel wegfällt, muss *all-* die Deklinationsendungen wie ein bestimmter Artikel bekommen: *aller (alte) Krempel, alle Mühe, alles Geld, trotz allem Streit, mit aller Gewalt, mit allem Gepäck* usw.. Eine Ausnahme gibt es beim Genitiv vor Substantiven mit Genitiv-s, dort heißt es nicht *all**es***, sondern *all**en***: *einschließlich all**en** Gepäck**s***.

Letzte Bemerkung: Umgangssprachlich hört man für **all(e)** (regional?) häufig **der ganze**, im Plural **die ganzen**, und in Kombination mit **mein** gibt es das als **mein ganzer**, im Plural **meine ganzen**. Obwohl der Ausdruck insgesamt Artikelfunktion hat, wird **ganz-** hier wie ein normales Adjektiv dekliniert:

- N: *Das ganze Zeug* kann in den Müll (geworfen werden).
- A: Der Idiot hat *seine ganzen Telefonnummern* aus den Kontakten gelöscht.
- D: *Mit seiner ganzen Anstrengung* hat er praktisch nichts erreicht.
- G: *Trotz dieser ganzen Aufregung* ist dann doch alles gut gelaufen.

Answer (score 2):

Adjektive beschreiben Eigenschaften (meist von Substantiven (*»das schöne Bild«*), manchmal auch Eigenschaften von Verben (*»Hanna singt schön«*) oder sogar von anderen Adjektiven (*»der Strich ist schön gerade«*)). Daher nennt man Adjektive auch »Eigenschaftswörter«.

Das Wort *»mein«* bezeichnet aber ein Besitzverhältnis. Dass eine Mahlzeit mir (oder sonst jemandem) gehört ist keine Eigenschaft der Mahlzeit. Das Wort gehört zu einer Klasse, die man »Fürwörter«, oder mit einem lateinischen Fachbegriff »Pronomen« nennt. (»Fürwort« ist einfach die wörtliche Übersetzung von »Pronomen«.) Fürwörter sind Wörter, die irgend eine Art von Beziehung anzeigen und in vielen Fällen anstelle eines Nomens (also *für* ein Nomen) stehen.

Es gibt viele verschiedene Arten von Fürwörtern, z.B.

- persönliche Fürwörter (Personalpronomen)

  > ich, du, er, ...
- besitzanzeigende Fürwörter (Possessivpronomen)

  > mein, dein, unser, ...
- hinweisende Fürwörter (Demonstrativpronomen)

  > dieser, jener, selbst, ...
- und noch viele mehr. Mehr darüber kann man z.B. bei [Café Lingua](https://www.cafe-lingua.de/deutsche-grammatik/pronomen-fuerwoerter.php) nachlesen.

Einige Fürwörter (Pronomen) haben mit Eigenschaftswörtern (Adjektiven) gemein, dass man sie als Beifügung (Attribut) zu einem Hauptwort (Substantiv) verwenden kann:

- Adjektiv als Attribut:

  > alle **leckeren** Mahlzeiten
- Pronomen als Attribut:

  > alle **meine** Mahlzeiten

Während aber *Adjektiv* und *Pronomen* Wortarten sind, ist *Attribut* eine grammatische Funktion.

Wortarten sind Klassen, zu denen bestimmte Wörter gehören, und zwar auch dann, wenn diese Wörter nicht in einem Satz stehen. Wenn man ein Wort in einem Wörterbuch wie z.B. Wiktionary nachschlägt, steht dort die Wortart:

- [lecker](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/lecker) ist ein Adjektiv
- [mein](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein) ist ein Possessivpronomen

Grammatische Funktionen sind aber Wirkungen innerhalb eines Satzgefüges. Ein und dasselbe Wort kann in verschiedenen Funktionen verwendet werden.

Beispiele:

- Attributive Verwendung eines Adjektivs

  > der **langsame** Bus
- Prädikative Verwendung eines Adjektivs

  > Der Bus ist **langsam.**
- Adverbielle Verwendung eines Adjektivs

  > Der Bus fährt **langsam.**

Aber dieselbe Funktion kann oftmals auch von einem Wort aus einer anderen Wortart ausgeübt werden:

- Adverbielle Verwendung eines Adverbs

  > Der Bus fährt **bereits.**

Der wesentliche Unterschied zwischen verschiedenen Wortarten ist, dass es für sie jeweils unterschiedliche Beugungsregeln gibt. Daher kann man die Regeln, nach denen man Adjektive beugen müsste, nicht auf Pronomen anwenden. Das geht selbst dann nicht, wenn sie im Satz dieselbe grammatische Funktion inne haben.

Comment: Die Sichtweise 'Pronomen als Attribut' erscheint mir überholt; die mir bekannten Sprachlehrwerke sprechen von _mein-, dein-_ usw. als Possessivartikeln. Sie teilen mit den Artikeln nicht nur das morphologische System der Endungen (bei den Possessivartikeln sind es die Endungen der unbestimmten Artikel) sondern auch die syntax-semantische Eigenschaft der Identifikation: _Von welcher Wohnung sprecht ihr? - Von deiner._ Es gibt auch Possessivpronomen mit teilweise abweichenden Endungen: _Der rote Stift ist mein**er**._ Possessivartikel bezeichnen keinen Besitz, sondern eine Zuordnung (mein Mann).